# Checkmarx Client DOM XSS violation in HTML

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, xss, checkmarx

In ***Checkmarx*** scan report, I got the following **Client DOM XSS** violation

**The application's `<div class="modal-header">` embeds untrusted data in the generated output with value, at line 1 of ***/master.component.html***. This untrusted data is embedded straight into the output without proper sanitization or encoding, enabling an attacker to inject malicious code into the output.**

The violation showing for the following HTML line in master.component.html,

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Update Event</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="onCloseClick()">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>


 <div class="modal-body">
        <form *ngIf="model" (ngSubmit)="save()" [formGroup]="fo
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                <label>Location</label>
                <div class="input-group mb-1">
                    <label class="custom-control custom-radio" for="international">
                        <input id="international" formControlName="location" name="location" type="radio" value="international" [checked]="form.get('location').value === 'international'" class="custom-control-input">
                        <span class="custom-control-label">International</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-group mb-1">
                    <label class="custom-control custom-radio" for="domestic">
                      <input id="domestic" formControlName="location" name="location" type="radio" value="domestic" [checked]="form.get('location').value === 'domestic'" class="custom-control-input">
                      <span class="custom-control-label">Domestic</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I can't find any clue on resolving this. Can anyone help me to find the fix?

Comment: are you using innerHTML binding anywhere?

Comment: @RiteshWaghela No

Comment: where is <div class="modal-header"> located, part of which component? Can you please add more code?

Comment: @RiteshWaghela added

Comment: <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> seems this one might be the issue, can you try replacing &times with X or some other icon?

Comment: @RiteshWaghela No it is not resolving.

Comment: @Hulk1991 did you figured what was the origin of the issue?

Comment: @Hulk1991 did you figure it out??